# How to debug single magento 2 file using xdebug in netbeans

Tags: magento-2.0, xdebug

I setup X-debug in my pc and magento 2 project added to netbeans, now debug magento2, it working fine, but I added new module for smtp configuration and i debug within the module file they show, "**You don't have permission to access /app/code/NameSpace/My Module/Model/Transport.php on this server**."

How to debug single magento 2 file using xdebug in nebeans.